# How do I walk recursively windows registry in lua?

Tags: windows, recursion, lua, registry

I'm coming from linux land so bear with me please.

I want to walk through windows registry recursively. All I've managed to do so far get the values of individual keys

```
> require 'luacom'
> sh = luacom.CreateObject "WScript.Shell"
> = sh:RegRead "HKCU\\Console\\ColorTable01"
8388608
```

yet see no way to iterate registry nodes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to do anything Windows-specific with Lua, your first port of call should be the [winapi](https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi) library; in this case, you can enumerate over Registry keys with [open_reg_key()](http://stevedonovan.github.com/winapi/api.html#Registry_Functions) and [Regkey:get_keys()](http://stevedonovan.github.com/winapi/api.html#Regkey:get_keys) like so:

```
require "winapi"
local key, err = winapi.open_reg_key [[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows]]
local t = key:get_keys()
for k,v in ipairs(t) do print(k,v) end
-- 1       CurrentVersion
-- 2       HTML Help
-- ...
```

Comment: is the only way to get the winapi library to build it yourself? or do you know of a pre-built binary already out there?

Comment: There used to be some prebuilt binaries hosted on GitHub, but since they got rid of the Downloads section a few months ago they've not shown up again.  It might be worth filing an issue on the repo to see if Steve will host them elsewhere; with that said, it's not particularly hard to build them yourself, just use TDM-GCC.